# Google Chrome and (cache or memory leaks)

Tags: javascript, caching, memory-leaks, google-chrome

I have a big problem with Google Chrome and its memory. My app is displaying to user several image charts and reloads them every 10s.

In the interval i have code like that

```
var image = new Image();
var src = 'myurl/image'+new Date().getTime();
image.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src = src;
    image.onload = image.onabort = image.onerror = null;
}
image.src = src;
```

So i have no memory leaks in Firefox and IE.

Here the response headers for images

```
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Vary * 
Cache-Control no-store (// I try no-cache, must-revalidate and so on here)
Content-Type image/png
Content-Length 11131
Date Mon, 31 May 2010 14:00:28 GMT
```

Vary * taken from [here](http://www.maintaino.com/nuts-and-bolts/2010/04/08/teaching-chrome-not-to-cache-your-rails-pages/)
In about:cache page there is no my cached images.

If i enable purge-memory-button for chrome (--purge-memory-button parameter) it`s not help.

Images is in PNG24.

So i think that the problem is not in cache.
May be Google Chrome is not releasing memory for old images.

Please help. Any suggestions.
Thanks.

*Update:*
Seems to be fixed http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142

Comment: I'm totally confused with your onload handling for the images... why are you setting up an onload handler then nullifying it? If the image has a unique path (even if it is visually the same image) you don't need to worry about it being cached. (note: new Date().getTime() doesn't guarantee uniqueness... depending on how/when it gets called)

Comment: You see the memory of Google Chrome process became 300MB in 15 minutes. And after 2-3 hours it`s crached.

Nullifying was set to prevent IE memory leak.

Comment: Do you have an example page, so we can step through your code?

Comment: No i have no example page, here is the code that executed from interval
http://pastebin.com/nAnPAgj5

Comment: You still use local variables from your interval function within a closure. Though the bug that you refer to also makes sense.

Comment: Here is very simple example, that also has huge memory leak. http://pastebin.com/XKzy2dKf
What i`m doing wrong? In FF and IE all is ok.

Comment: Hmm, that should not go wrong at all. But as [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142#c3) implies, this is probably a WebKit bug. A [quick search](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=image+memory+leak) didn't reveal an open bug, but I'll go on searching within a few hours.

Comment: This bug is still not fixed(((((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an issue in chromium bug tracker [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142) so may be it`s a google-chrome bug.

**EDIT**

Issue is already fixed